# Problema ao alertar quando valido os campos

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema na mensagem que é impressa da validação do meu formulário, ela só é impressa corretamente quando o ultimo campo não é preenchido ou é preenchido, ou seja o problema é na execução do loop. Segue o meu código HTML:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nome Completo</label>
        <input id="nomeCompleto" type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" maxlength="40" onkeypress="return letras()">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Modelo do Veículo</label>
        <input id="modeloDoVeiculo" type="text" name="modelo" maxlength="40" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Placa do Veículo</label>
        <input id="placaDoVeiculo" type="text" name="placa" class="form-control" maxlength="8">
    </div>
    <div class="alert text-center" id="apareceAlerta" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="adicionar" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="alertaCadastro()">
    </div>
</form>
```

E meu código JavaScript:

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
formulario.addEventListener("submit",cadastrarVeiculo);
function cadastrarVeiculo(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++){
        var elemento = this.elements[i];
        if (elemento.type != "submit") {
            alertaDeCadastro = document.getElementById("apareceAlerta");
            let isValid;
            if (elemento.value == "") {
                elemento.parentNode.classList.add("has-error");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Os campos acima não foram preenchidos corretamente!";
                alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
            }else{
                elemento.parentNode.classList.remove("has-error");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
                alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que ele verifica todos os elemento, e o que vai valer é apenas o ultimo. Pois nos anteriores ele ta colocando não preenchido, mas no ultimo, se tiver preenchido, vai sobreescrever o anterior.

Minha solução é forçar o i a ser igual o tamanho de elementos, assim ele já sai do loop no momento que o value for vazio ou você pode usar o while e sair do loop quando o valor do elemento for vazio:

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
formulario.addEventListener("submit",cadastrarVeiculo);
alertaDeCadastro= '';
function cadastrarVeiculo(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();

    for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++){
        var elemento = this.elements[i];
        if (elemento.type != "submit") {
            alertaDeCadastro = document.getElementById("apareceAlerta");
            let isValid;
            if (elemento.value == "") {
                elemento.parentNode.classList.add("has-error");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Os campos acima não foram preenchidos corretamente!";
                alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
                i = this.elements.length;
            }else{
                elemento.parentNode.classList.remove("has-error");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
                alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente, apesar de que eu estava procurando manter a classe has-error em todos os elementos que apontassem erro e não apenas o primeiro deles, mas já consegui.

Comment: Olha cara, o que você pode fazer para isso, é no final (fora do loop) verificar se tem algum elemento com a classe 'has-error', ai sim vc coloca a div com a mensagem de erro, se essa classe é existente.

Comment: fiz do jeito abaixo, ta um pouquinho mais extenso, mas já funciona

Answer (score 2):

Solução para que todos os campos em branco sejam destacados e não apenas o primeiro deles:

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
formulario.addEventListener("submit",cadastrarVeiculo);
function cadastrarVeiculo(evento){
var nomeCompleto = document.getElementById("nomeCompleto"),
modeloDoVeiculo = document.getElementById("modeloDoVeiculo"),
placaDoVeiculo = document.getElementById("placaDoVeiculo"),
horaEntrada = new Date();
var isValid;
evento.preventDefault();
for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++){
    var elemento = this.elements[i];
    if (elemento.type != "submit") {
        alertaDeCadastro = document.getElementById("apareceAlerta");
        if (elemento.value == "") {
            elemento.parentNode.classList.add("has-error");
            if ((nomeCompleto.value == "")||(modeloDoVeiculo.value == "")||(placaDoVeiculo.value == "")) {
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Os campos acima não foram preenchidos corretamente!";
            }
            alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            elemento.parentNode.classList.remove("has-error");
            alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-danger");
            alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-success");
            alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
            isValid = true;
            if ((nomeCompleto.value == "")||(modeloDoVeiculo.value == "")||(placaDoVeiculo.value == "")) {
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.remove("alert-success");
                alertaDeCadastro.classList.add("alert-danger");
                alertaDeCadastro.innerHTML = "Os campos acima não foram preenchidos corretamente!";
                isValid = false;
            }
            alertaDeCadastro.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
if (isValid == true) {
    console.log("cadastrou");
}
```

}